# Why doesn't vertical scroll bar appear in the element block when it's overflowed?

Tags: html, css

I've got a .showGuesses block which max-height is set to 100px. When its height goes over its maximum I want a vertical scroll bar to appear. But, unfortunately, for some reason I never get the scroll bar.

**How to make the scrollbar to appear?**

Here's the code and the result: https://liveweave.com/hyo1ut

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form class="order-form" method="POST" action="insert_data.php">
                <legend>Insert your address</legend>
                
                <div class="input-area-wrap">
                    <div class="input-area">
                        <label>street/avenue</label>
                        <input type="text" name="street" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="showGuesses">
                        <div class="showGuess">Street 1</div>
                        <div class="showGuess">Street 2</div>
                        <div class="showGuess">Street 3</div>
                        <div class="showGuess">Street 4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box!important;
            box-sizing: border-box!important;
}
.order-form {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
         -ms-flex-direction: column;
             flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: unset!important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
legend {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px!important;
}
.input-area-wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
}
.input-area {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: baseline;
        -ms-flex-align: baseline;
            align-items: baseline;
    position: relative;
}
.input-area label {
    width: 150px;
}
input[type="text"] {
    width: 250px!important;
    outline: none;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 2px solid darkred!important;
    outline: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgb(255, 74, 74);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.showGuesses {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 3;
    /* top: 25px; */
    margin-left: 150px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.showGuess {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

**UPD 0:**

Due to help of @EssXTee I now get the scrollbar, but it doesn't disappear if the content of showGuesses block doesn't overflow it. It's just there all the time for some reason.

**How to fix that?**

Comment: I've changed the language to English in several places*

Comment: Also changed that in the playground

Comment: The scrollbar actually does appear, but you can't see it because it's too far to the right. Basically, your `showGuesses` class has a width of **100%** but also has a left margin of **150px**. This causes it to have the full width of its parent but shifted to the right by 150 pixels (which is where the scroll bar is). If you adjust the width on the `showGuesses` class you can see your scrollbar.

Comment: @EssXTee you can write it as a brief answer and I can then mark it as solution if you want to

Comment: @EssXTee but now I'm having another problem. The scrollbar is always there no matter whether the content of showGuesses overcomes the maximum height or not

Comment: I posted an official answer, and also an update to fix your scrollbar always showing issue. Using `overflow-y: auto;` instead of `scroll` only shows the scrollbar when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting this answer so there is an official solution.

The scrollbar does appear but it seems that it is too far right on the screen to be seen. This is because the `.showGuesses` class has a width of 100%, but also a left margin of 150 pixels. This makes the `.showGuesses` div the same size as the parent, but shifted to the right by 150 pixels. And this is where the scrollbar is.

So simply reducing the width of the `.showGuesses` class does fix this. As far as what to set the width to, I suppose that's a preference of where you would like the scrollbar to appear.

**EDIT**
As far as the scrollbar always being visible, use `overflow-y: auto;` instead of setting it to `scroll`, which will always show a scrollbar. Using `auto` only shows the scrollbar if needed.

Answer (score 1):

"replace the code block "`<div class="showGuesses">`" with "`<div class="showGuesses" style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">`" with this

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box!important;
            box-sizing: border-box!important;
}
.order-form {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
         -ms-flex-direction: column;
             flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: unset!important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
legend {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px!important;
}
.input-area-wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
}
.input-area {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: baseline;
        -ms-flex-align: baseline;
            align-items: baseline;
    position: relative;
}
.input-area label {
    width: 150px;
}
input[type="text"] {
    width: 250px!important;
    outline: none;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 2px solid darkred!important;
    outline: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgb(255, 74, 74);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.showGuesses {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 3;
    /* top: 25px; */
    margin-left: 150px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.showGuess {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    padding: 5px
```

```html
<form class="order-form" method="POST" action="insert_data.php">
                <legend>Введите адрес</legend>
                
                <div class="input-area-wrap">
                    <div class="input-area">
                        <label>Улица/Проспект</label>
                        <input type="text" name="street" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="showGuesses" style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                        <div class="showGuess">Street 1</div>
                        <div class="showGuess">Street 2</div>
                        <div class="showGuess">Street 3</div>
                        <div class="showGuess">Street 4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Looks ok, but why is this the solution?